# Pandas: access to rows by filtering by date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

When doing:

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime
timestampparse = lambda t: datetime.fromtimestamp(float(t))
df = pandas.read_csv('blah.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=True, date_parser=timestampparse, index_col='DateTime', names=['DateTime', 'Sell'], header=None)
print df.ix['2015-12-02 12:02:21.070':'2015-12-02 12:40:21.070']
```

with this blah.csv file:

```
1449054136.83;1.05905
1449054139.25;1.05906
1449054139.86;1.05906
1449054140.47;1.05906
```

I get this error:

> KeyError

**How to access to a slice of a pandas dataframe, filtered by date?**

**Why doesn't `df.ix['2015-12-02 12:02:19.000':'2015-12-02 12:40:21.070']` work?**

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? I have `0.17.1` worked as you exected with `df.ix["2015-12-02 14:02:16.829999":"2015-12-02 14:02:19.859999"]`

Comment: I have `0.17.1` installed with `pip install pandas` on Windows + Python 2.7.

Comment: Could you show your dataframe after parsers?

Comment: When using `14:02:19.859999` it works, but using `14:02:19.859` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad the second fractions with zeros `'2015-12-02 12:02:16.0859'`:

```
>>> df['2015-12-02 12:02:16.0859':'2015-12-02 12:03:20'])
                              Sell
DateTime                           
2015-12-02 12:02:16.829999  1.05905
2015-12-02 12:02:19.250000  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:19.859999  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:20.470000  1.05906
```

This works:

```
>>> df['2015-12-02 12:02:17':'2015-12-02 12:03:20']
                               Sell
DateTime                           
2015-12-02 12:02:19.250000  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:19.859999  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:20.470000  1.05906
```

This works with version 0.16.2

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df[datetime(2015, 12, 2, 12, 2, 16):datetime(2015, 12, 2, 12, 2, 20)]

                               Sell
DateTime                           
2015-12-02 12:02:16.829999  1.05905
2015-12-02 12:02:19.250000  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:19.859999  1.05906
```

Comment: Thanks! How to get the DateTime (i.e. the index) of row 3? I tried `df['DateTime'][2]` but I get `KeyError: 'DateTime'`

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work, because in `datetimeindex` and `floatindex` can be precision problem.

You can use [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing), where I omit numbers on the end of datetime - I use only seconds:

```
print df['2015-12-02 12:02:19':'2015-12-02 12:40:20']

                            Sell
DateTime                        
2015-12-02 12:02:19.250  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:19.860  1.05906
2015-12-02 12:02:20.470  1.05906
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, small thing, how to get the DateTime (i.e. the index) of row 3? I tried `df['DateTime'][2]` but I get `KeyError: 'DateTime'`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. The output  of `df.iloc[2]` is `Sell    1.05906
Name: 2015-12-02 12:02:19.860000, dtype: float64`. it seems that @MikeMüller's `df.index[2]` is more adapted to my needs : the output is just `2015-12-02 12:02:19.860000`.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) and from [Time/Date Components](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components) as I understand you need to specify amount for microseconds (the same as for datetime objects):

```
In [103]: df.loc["2015-12-02 14:02:10":"2015-12-02 14:02:19.899999"]
Out[103]:
                               Sell
DateTime
2015-12-02 14:02:16.829999  1.05905
2015-12-02 14:02:19.250000  1.05906
2015-12-02 14:02:19.859999  1.05906
```

Or use `datetime` for specify exactly amount of microseconds:

```
In [104]: df.loc["2015-12-02 14:02:10":datetime(year=2015, month=12, day=2, hour=14, minute=2, second=20, microsecond=999999)]
Out[104]:
                               Sell
DateTime
2015-12-02 14:02:16.829999  1.05905
2015-12-02 14:02:19.250000  1.05906
2015-12-02 14:02:19.859999  1.05906
2015-12-02 14:02:20.470000  1.05906
```